# Song played in Episode 77 start of My Hero Academia Season 4

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

In episode 77 of the anime Boku No Hero Academia Season 4, what is the name of the song played at the start with that glitchy tune?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I love that one too! It’s track 43 from the second season’s original soundtrack. A video transcribed the title as “Honki de Tatakitsubusu Shozon.” Not sure if that’s correct, but hope it helps![image]